Saying solution of a PDE is continuous to the boundary
Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain and $u$ is a function on it such that $\Delta u$ converges to $0$ at every boundary point of $\Omega$, can we say from here that $u$ extends continuously to the boundary of $\Omega$? Does it follow from some elliptic regularity theory ? Do we need some condition on boundary of $\Omega$ for this to happen ?
Is it possible to get some concrete reference on this (like some particular theorem in some books/notes)?

Gilbarg and Trudinger’s Elliptic Partial Differential Equations.

No.  Let $\Phi$ be the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation (aka the Newton potential).  It has a singularity at $0$.  Now if $y \in \partial \Omega$ then the map $u(x) = \Phi(x-y)$ satisfies $\Delta u(x) =0$ for $x \in \Omega$, but $u$ has a singularity at $y$ and so does not extend continuously to $\partial \Omega$.

Interesting. Thanks
